# How to manually verify apk signatures and compare signing keys

Tags: android, linux, shell, command-line

Suppose I have two .apk files, supposedly from the same developer.
How do I verify that they are signed with the same key?
How do I verify that the key belongs to the developer?

In which Android download does the right tool exist?
I do not seem to find it in 
commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip nor 
android-studio-ide-192.6392135-linux.tar.gz

Answer (score 7):

You need apksigner tool to verify apk.

You have two options to take it:

1) Download last buildtools by **SdkManger in Android Studio**.
- See instruction https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

2) **Manual downloading**:
- Got to https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads and select Command line tools
package for your OS (for example click on "commandlinetools-mac-6200805_latest.zip" button for mac os)

- Agree with the above terms and conditions and download commandlinetools
- unpack commandlinetools (you will receive folder with name "tools" )
- go to tools/bin folder
- execute cmd > `./sdkmanager --list --sdk_root=''`

('sdk_root' argument can be a path to android sdk or empty if you have not it)

- find last build-tools version. in my case it:
  `"build-tools;29.0.3 | 29.0.3 | Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3"`
- execute cmd > `./sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.3"  --sdk_root=''`

(download build-tools to current folder)

**Next steps:**

- When you will have /build-tools/29.0.3/apksigner cmd tool
- execute cmd > `./apksigner verify -v --print-certs  /Users/you/Desktop/my_app.apk`

(I execute the cmd from folder which contains apksigner file) 
- You will receive information like this:

```
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Google Inc., L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: f0fd6c5b410f25cb25c3b53346c8972fae30f8ee7411df910480ad6b2d60db83
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 38918a453d07199354f8b19af05ec6562ced5788
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: cde9f6208d672b54b1dacc0b7029f5eb
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 2b06490d2d24305c6a90dbf74cc42f50183d207d572f8079e5d92fb2c2a0cda1
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: b2da9ef7ec0f4474117fb0cba4dca3b795c0eab7
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: a90ce510a96aa09bee6bf8d9da9b258b
```

Answer (score 0):

#1. Open a command prompt or terminal window and navigate to the directory where the APK files are located.

#2. Verify the signature of the first APK by running the following command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app1.apk
```

This command will print information about the signing certificate used to sign the APK.

#3. Save the certificate information to a file by running the following command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -certs app1.apk > app1.txt
```

#4. Save the certificate information to a file by running the following command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -certs app1.apk > app1.txt
```

This command will save the certificate information to a text file named app1.txt.

#5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for the second APK, saving the certificate information to a text file named app2.txt.

#6. Compare the certificate information in the two text files to see if the signing keys match. You can use a diff tool or a text editor to compare the files.

Please let me know if it helps you.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all 6 of recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).